# resize a bitmap with a image, use it as background

Tags: android, image, bitmap, resize, resolution

i'm trying to make a game for android.

now I have to put a image into a bitmap and resize it to fit the width and height of the device.

When i try to make that i see a picture that the picture is greater than the screen. I want that the bitmap fits into the screen.

Thanks for your help.

here is a part of my code:

*class GameView*

```
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.foto);
background = new BackGround(this,bmp);
```

*class Background*

```
public class BackGround {

       private Bitmap bmp;
       private int width;
       private int height;

       public BackGround(GameView gameView, Bitmap bmp) {
             this.bmp = bmp;
             this.width = bmp.getWidth();
             this.height = bmp.getHeight();
       }
         public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

             Rect src = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
             Rect dst = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
             canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, src, dst, null);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just added this code in my onDraw to dynamically size based on the screen (to handle portrait and landscape modes).

```
final int canvasWidth = getWidth();
final int canvasHeight = getHeight();

int imageWidth = originalImage.getWidth();
int imageHeight = originalImage.getHeight();

float scaleFactor = Math.min( (float)canvasWidth / imageWidth, 
                              (float)canvasHeight / imageHeight );
Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(  originalImage, 
                                            (int)(scaleFactor * imageWidth), 
                                            (int)(scaleFactor * imageHeight), 
                                            true );
```

Comment: Hah, good point.  I believe I had a guard to prevent the scaling from occurring every time, but since then I moved the scaling code to a much more appropriate place - surfaceCreated() (and another for when the image is updated).  It's cleaner and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Rect dst = new Rect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());